# Error handling with lapply -- output the index of failed elements

Tags: r, error-handling, lapply

[Answer to question about error handling with lapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721097/error-handling-with-lapply) always return `NA` or `NULL` when an element fails, i.e.

```
myfun <- function(s) {
  tryCatch(doSomething(s), error = function(e) { return(NULL) }
}
```

However, this is not general enough since `doSomething(s)` may return `NULL` or `NA` itself. Therefore, ideally I want `myfun` written so that after `lapply(mylist, myfun)` I can somehow get all the indices of failed elements. How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Catch and release the error by handing it with `identity()`

```
res = lapply(list(1, "two", 3), function(i) tryCatch({
    sqrt(i)
}, error=identity)
```

Check for errors

```
vapply(res, is, logical(1), "error")
```

Returning the error condition is often better the returning a 'magic' value like `NA` or `NULL`, unless the down-stream analysis works seamlessly with the value returned.

As a more advanced solution, create a more elaborate condition or extend the error class

```
my_condition = function(err)
    structure(list(message=conditionMessage(err),
                   original=err), class=c("my", "condition"))
```

and return that

```
res <- lapply(list(1, "two", 3), function(i) {
    tryCatch({
        sqrt(i)
    }, error=my_condition)
})
```